# How to understand scale expansion in Fokker-Planck equation

Tags: quantum-optics, stochastic-processes

I read the book *Statistical Methods in Quantum Optics 1 (Master equations and Fokker-Planck equations)*, published by springer.

In Chapter $5$, to do scale expansion, the writer introduces a system-size parameter $\Omega$. $x$ is a parameter in **microscopic unit** related to state of the system, for example, the photon number in cavity. Then the system can be described by a probability function $P(x,t)$, satisfying the generalized Fokker-Planck equation:

$$\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}=\sum\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{n}}(\frac{\partial}{\partial x})^{k}(a_{k}(x)P)\tag {1}$$

Then

$$x=\Omega^{p} \bar{x}_{0}(t)+\Omega^{p-q}\epsilon\tag {2}$$

where $\bar{x}_{0}$ is parameter related to $x$, but in **macroscopic unit**, for example, photon number density or energy density in cavity. $\epsilon$ is the fluctuation due to quantum effects or interactions with environment.

Then to linearize the generalized Fokker-Planck equation, a new function is introduced:

$$\bar{P}=\Omega^{p-q}P(\Omega^{p} \bar{x}_{0}(t)+\Omega^{p-q}\epsilon,t)\tag {3}$$

Then the generalized Fokker-Planck equation becomes:

$$\frac{\partial\bar{P}}{\partial t}=\Omega^{p-q}\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial \bar{x}_{0}(t)}\frac{d \bar{x}_{0}(t)}{d t}+\frac{\partial P}{\partial t}\right)=\Omega^{q}\frac{\partial \bar{P}}{\partial \epsilon}\frac{d \bar{x}_{0}(t)}{d t}+\sum\frac{(-1)^{k}}{k^{n}}\left(\Omega^{q-p}\frac{\partial}{\partial \epsilon}\right)^{k}(a_{k}\bar{P})$$ $$\tag {4}$$

So here is **My first question**:

> Why in equation $(2)$, the mean value $\bar{x}_{0}(t)$ and fluctuation $\epsilon$ multiply different powers of $\Omega$? My assumption is perhaps the fluctuation has size effect, which can change fluctuation density, resulting in different powers of $\Omega$. If so, $q$ seems to indicate some intrinsic property of the system. Should it relates to some other degree of freedom besides the one determining $p$, thus $q$ cannot be obtained from Fokker-Planck equation alone?

However, the writer says $q$ should be found self-consistently solving the equation.

**My second question** arises from here:

The author says:

$$a_{k}(\Omega^{p}\bar{x}_{0}(t))=\Omega^{k(p-1)+1}\bar{a}_{k}(\bar{x}_{0}(t))\tag {5}$$

And gives some explanation, which I cannot understand.

> Can some one explain to me why $(5)$ holds or give some reference?

Comment: The classical reference on FPE is the Risken's book: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540615309